# handlebars equality check in if/else block

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I wrote the below if else condition in handlebars template but every time its going in else part even my emps.marital_status value is married.

```
{{#if ('emps.marital_status  "married"') }}
    married
{{else}}
    unmarried
{{/if }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Handlebars does not support equality check in `if` blocks. You need register your own helper:

```
handlebars.registerHelper('ifvalue', function (conditional, options) {
  if (options.hash.value === conditional) {
    return options.fn(this)
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});
```

And use it:

```
{{#ifvalue emps.marital_status value="married"}}
    married
{{else}}
    unmarried
{{/ifvalue}}
```

Comment: I using express framework but i little confused about how can i register helper can you guide me.

Comment: @NirajSavaliya If you are using `exress-handlebars` library, this will help: https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#helpers